# FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 cannot recognize input near 'USING' 'org' in table name (USING org.apache.spark.sql.json)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I would like to use the following query, but I get an error. As I read here https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html the query should be correct.

```
CREATE TABLE spark_logs USING org.apache.spark.sql.json OPTIONS (path "/data/web_logs/clicks.json");


NoViableAltException(275@[184:1: tableName : (db= identifier DOT tab=
identifier -> ^( TOK_TABNAME $db $tab) |tab= identifier -> ^(
TOK_TABNAME $tab) );])
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.tableName(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:4692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableName(HiveParser.java:44923)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1473)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 cannot recognize input near
'spark_logs' 'USING' 'org' in table name
```

Do you have an idea why hive could not recognize `USING org.apache.spark.sql.json`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult fresh documentation ([Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html)), not something that is written ~5 years ago :-)
The syntax is following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name 
USING JSON 
LOCATION 'path....';
```

Update: It looks like that in the 1.6.x, the only supported syntax is as described in the blog post (temporary table, but not the Hive table):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE people
    USING org.apache.spark.sql.json
    OPTIONS (path '[the path to the JSON dataset]')
```

Comment: What version of Spark?

Comment: Spark version is 1.6.0.

Comment: Spark 1.6 is quite different beast, the temporary table works, but not `create table`